# Unable to find JAXBContext for media type: application/octet-stream

Tags: jaxb, resteasy

I am working with RestEasy and when I type the url `http://localhost:8080/resteasy/xml` I want to see a "Save As..." option in firefox.

```
@GET
@Path("/xml")
@Produces("application/octet-stream")
public List<FileDetail> getXmlContent() {
    return findXml();
}
```

But when I use this, I get the error:

`Unable to find JAXBContext for media type: application/octet-stream`

What is wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your want the 'Save as' dialog to appear in the browser, you can add the `Content-Disposition`-header in the response

```
@Path("/")
public class Service {
    @Context HttpResponse response;

    @GET
    @Path("/xml")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<FileDetail> getXmlContent() {
        response.getOutputHeaders().putSingle("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=list.xml");

        List<FileDetail> data = new ArrayList<FileDetail>();
        data.add(new FileDetail());

        return data;
    }
}
```